# JavaScript (WebGL) open-source raytracers (non-realtime)

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, raytracing

I want to render an image using RayTracing algorithm in browser and send rendered bitmap to server. It's possible achieve this using WebGL / JavaScript? If it's possible, so which non-realtime open-source raytracer I can use?

Comment: Why not use realtime raytracer and send result when rendering process is done?

Comment: @fedosov because I want to render high-resolution images. So rendering time will take minutes or hours.

Comment: Real-time raytracers can generate hi-resolution images. Caustic.com is one example, there are others.

Comment: Any Turing complete language (such as Javascript) with a draw_pixel routine (e.g., look at canvas in Javascript) can do raytracing. What is your particular issue with the implementation ? If you're just looking for a list of pre-made libraries, I'm not sure SO is the right place to ask.

Comment: @WhitAngl in fact in my post 2 questions. And first question is more important for me: it's possible using  latest JavaScript API, HTML5, WebGL, etc cause client's browser to render big image (non-realtime, because rendering of high-resolution images is very time-consumption), then cause client to send rendered image as bitmap back to the server..I want to use client's resources (CPU, GPU) (through browser) to render very big images (of course with client's agreement). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[OCLToys](http://code.google.com/p/ocltoys/) includes an open source OpenCL path tracer (SmallPTGPU). There is also a [WebCL version](https://ocltoys.googlecode.com/hg/web/webcl/smallptgpu/webcl-smallptgpu.html) that could be easily adapted to perform your task.